# Mutual exclusive parallelism

Tags: git, cmake

In my project I use several different git repositories that I need to `git pull` from time to time. I'd like to update these in parallel for speed. In a shell script, the merge outputs can interleave such that I do not know which repositories have actually been updated. So I use Ninja (which caches the outputs until the command finishes and then outputs them in the order the commands finished) using the following CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project("gitupdate" NONE)
find_package(Git)

function(update_git _dir _remote _branch)
  set(_fulldir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${_dir}")

  add_custom_target("${_dir}-${_remote}-${_branch}" ALL
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${_fulldir}
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} pull ${_remote} ${_branch}
    COMMENT "Updating ${_dir} ${_remote} ${_branch}..."
    VERBATIM
  )
endfunction()
```

This works fine until I have a git dir that updates from several remotes. E.g.

```
update_git(subproject remoteA master)
update_git(subproject remoteB master)
```

Can I somehow tell CMake to not execute these targets at the same time?

PS: Git syntax coloring is gone from output cached by Ninja. Any chance to keep these?

Comment: The coloring can be recovered by passing the git commands the flag `--color=always`, so that it will ignore the fact that its output is not going directly to a TTY.

Comment: @Novelocrat Doesn't work: `error: unknown option `color=always'`. `git config --global color.ui always` doesn't work either. Note that this is MSYS bash --rxvt. Windows terminal doesn't understand ANSI escape codes, no idea about rxvt.

Answer (score 0):

Make the generated custom targets depend on each other. This should force Ninja to execute the targets sequentially:

```
update_git(subproject remoteA master)
update_git(subproject remoteB master)
add_dependencies(subproject-remoteA-master subproject-remoteB-master)
```